# android-x86 7.1-r2 (Nougat) on a Lenovo PC has kernel bug with wireless card

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, android, android-x86

i put the most recent version of android-x86 on a Lenovo touch screen PC and everything works great... except the wifi.

it never finds any networks and says disabled in settings with no way to enable it.

From dmesg I see this error:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=186161

People also talking about it here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1627474

There doesn’t seem to be any fix yet. Where do I go from here to try and patch the kernel? Or I guess just getting a USB Network stick and not using ath10k driver at all might be easier.

Comment: If the wifi is not working, it is highly likely that the Android image you installed doesn't have the driver for your wifi card.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1627474 Has the same issue as this box, it’s a firmware crash error with ath10k I found this message from dmesg

Comment: on my tablet the broadcom Wifi is also not working. here I use an USB 3.0 1Gbit LAN adapter to have network connection. try USB wifi devices until you found a working one.

Comment: Well I tried https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073DYXRSZ/ no luck. Shame this Levono touch screen PC is just perfect for android. Apps fill the whole screen perfectly, touch screen interface is spot on.

Comment: try the Android x86 8.1 ISO that was just released.